# Suggestions to new sort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting

I thought about new sorting algorithm, and I couldn't understand the problem in the obvious solution:

```
public int[] sort(int[] arr){

    //Find the biggest number in the array
    int max=1;
    for(int i : arr)
        if(i>max)
            max=i;

    //Sorting the figures into big array
    int[] LongSorted= new int[max+1];
    for(int i=1; i<LongSorted.length; i++)
        LongSorted[i]=0;
    for(int i : arr)
        LongSorted[i]+=i;

    //Transfer the sorted figures into the original array
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        while(LongSorted[index]==0){
            index++;
        }
        arr[i]=index;
        if(LongSorted[index]!=(index)){
            for(int j=0; j<(LongSorted[index]/index)-1; j++){
                i++;
                arr[i]=index;
            }
        }
        index++;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Basically, the algorithm use the figure's value as index.

If you want to **use** this method, please be aware that the figure '0' is not considered.
You may correct it by the follow instructions:
 **1**. Change the LongSorted type to 'Integer'.
 **2**. Change the value of 'i' in the LongSorted's initialize "for" to '1'.
 **3**. A previous line before the last "for", add the following condition:

```
       if(LongSorted[0]!=null)
          arr[0]=0;
```

**4**. Change the value of 'i' in the last "for" to '1'.
**Tnx!**

Comment: Your alg will fail in we have negatives in array

Comment: It will also fail if you have duplicate values. And you do realize that this algorithm could use gigabytes of memory if there is a large value in that array?

Comment: Let's sort this array `{2, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 1}`. It has 3 entries. Your line `int[] LongSorted= new int[max+1];` will create an array with more than two billion entries to sort my 3 numbers. That sounds like a big waste of space.

Comment: Duplicate values is not a problem. Read the end of the code. (I add the index of the original element to the value that's already in the array tracking locations).

Comment: This is not new. It's just a very poor implementation of a special case of radix sort. Something similar was published to universal derision in ACM SIGPLAN Notices in about 1988. Not a real question.

Answer (score 3):

If this is supposed to be at all efficient - it's not. First of all, you loop through various arrays many times. Some of these aren't necessary, and they slow the algorithm down on large sets of data.

Second, what happens if you try to sort the following list? [1; 1000000000]

You'll end up creating an array of size 1 billion+1 just to sort two numbers. That's 4 billion bytes.

Finally, what happens if there are duplicate elements?

And then as pointed out in the comments, this will fail on negative numbers.

If you came up with this idea entirely on your own, and are new to programming, then you're actually on the right track to something really important - a [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

Comment: Actually, duplicates will not be overwritten, they will be lost and potentially create new values (he adds the index of the original element to the value that's already in the array tracking locations.

Comment: Actually, I must correct myself. It's even more messed up and leads to an unsorted result. Just throw this away and use a classic sort ;-)

Comment: Actually, it does sort positive numbers and handle duplicates, as long as you don't include a large enough number that the big array blows memory.  It is however a horrid sort implementation.

Answer (score 0):

***I must come to the rescue:***

Admittedly it very depends, whether this algorithm is efficient, and it covers only positive values > 0.
But it is a good idea and might in border cases be nicely efficient.

I have rewritten it a bit more read-friendly, still with in-place sorting:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] arr) {

    // Find the biggest number in the array
    int max = 1;
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i > max) {
            max = i;
        }
    }

    // Sorting the figures into big array
    // indexOccurrences[i] is how often the value i occures in arr.
    int[] indexOccurrences = new int[max + 1];
    for (int i : arr) {
        ++indexOccurrences[i];
    }

    // Transfer the sorted figures into the original array
    int arrIndex = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < indexOccurrences.length; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < indexOccurrences[j]; ++k) {
            arr[arrIndex] = j;
            ++arrIndex;
        }
    }
    assert arrIndex == arr.length;
    return arr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = new int[] { 23, 6, 67, 6, 6, 45, 3 };
    values = sort(values);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

[3, 6, 6, 6, 23, 45, 67]

BTW the idea is not new, but that might seen as a support of it.